# 64GB sd card shrunk to 4GB after cloning

Tags: windows, sd-card

I just cloned a SanDisk 4GB Sandisk micro SD card onto a Samsung Evo 64GB card, and now my new card shows a 4GB.

I used HDDRawCopy to do this. Can anyone tell me how to reverse this back to 64GB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the file system was also copied to the 64GB card. The file system says it is 4GB.

If you still want your data in the card, you need to adjust it with some partitioning tools, like this one: http://www.disk-partition.com/ AOMEI. It has a free edition for Windows users. I think it can be used to adjust the partition size. If it cannot, you may need to move out your files, delete the 4GB partition, and create a new one.

If you use Linux, you may want to use`gparted`.

Comment: Or use GParted on a Linux virtual machine (you can get those with a small download of around 100MB) or just use the virtual disk manager, built-in in Windows. And extend the primary active partition.

Comment: Have you ever tried VDM built-in Windows on USB flash drives? I don't think it is well compatible with partitions on a USB flash drive or an SD card.

Comment: Depends on your card reader. I guess. I tried with a pendrive, but without any luck. But, as far as I know, not every car reader is connected to the USB, and may allow these changes.

Comment: I guess if Windows finds that the device is an SD card, it will not allow partitioning functionalities to work in VDM. However, you are right, that depends on the card reader implementation.

Comment: Lets just say that, by some misterious miracle and after all the planets align, virtual disk manager *may* work in the SD card reader. If you aren't feeling lucky, use something else. Is it a fair judgement?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have this problem is that the volume you copied over is smaller than the drive you copied it onto. The simplest way to fix this is to reformat the drive, also called repartitioning.

However, you could also expand the 4Gb volume to fill the new disk. You may be able to do this with the same tool you used for cloning. I know [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) can do this, but it is for advanced and/or careful users, so YMMV.

Comment: Reformatting alone likely won't fix this. More likely, repartitioning is needed. Thankfully, these days, extending existing partitions is a relatively low-risk operation, and even more so for memory cards that hold no critical data.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Sorry, that's what I meant. I meant reformatting the drive, not just one volume. Thanks for mentioning this.